# Slider compatible issue with IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, slider

I bought a bootstrap template [appster](http://wbpreview.com/previews/WB005EL63/) online. The slider is not compatible with my IE7 and IE8 as show in the following image:

[image]

Does anybody know how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without the code in Public Domain, we will not be able to say anything.

Comment: @PraveenKumar You can check the code using chrome. Should I paste the code here?

Comment: It has something to do with the filter on the images. you could try setting: .pics img { filter:  none !important;}

Comment: @ScottSimpson I have tried to set it in the appster.css, but doesn't work. Is this bug caused by the js?

Comment: Is there a demo somewhere? I respect your privacy. ;) It seems to be the normal IE 7 and IE 8 fixes. If there are files like IE7.css or IE8.css, are they loading?

Comment: @PraveenKumar please check the link: http://wbpreview.com/previews/WB005EL63/  btw:there is no file like IE7.css

Comment: Yup. Its opening now. :) Chrome looks good. Checking in IE 7 and 8...

Comment: The `filter: alpha(opacity=0);` isn't working... If this is the case with the original file, then yeah, the author had given it with the bug. *ps: Get for a refund! ;)*

Comment: I guess you will be needing this: http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/

Comment: @PraveenKumar After setting the opacity the alpha animation is gone, and the background color still be there.

Comment: No no... I said something has to be done in the script. Not just the CSS... :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar Oops! The js is unreadable, it's query.cycle.all.min.js

Comment: Oh okay... It should be `jquery.cycle.all.min.js`. Anyways, get the full version from http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ and check if it is working and if they are same. Updating the plugin may solve that issue?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I update the js but not work.

Comment: What I am asking is, is the slider functioning as expected after you updating the script, css, and html, if needed?

Comment: @PraveenKumar No, not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution.

add this css :

.right-side img{background-color: none !important;}

Comment: yes this should work. or you can also add background: none !important;

Comment: .right-side img{background: none !important;} is the solution, thanks:)